# How do I separate a stream of `1`s and `2`s into groups?

Tags: haskell

Imagine I have a *really* long file like this:

```
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
1
1
1
1
2
2
1
1
2
2
...
```

I'm interested in separating and performing computation on each group of consecutive `1`s along with the consecutive `2`s that come immediately after it.

*However*, the problem is somewhat more complicated in reality. First, the records are not simply `1`s and `2`s but something larger, let's say individual `Record`s, and it requires some computation to determine whether a `Record` is `1` or `2`; second, instead of exposed as a file, the data source only exposes it self with a retrieving function, let's say `get1 :: IO (Maybe Record)`. This function returns one record `Just record` with each call, and returns `Nothing` when the data is depleted; and finally, the file is large (effectively infinite), I have to do it in a stream-lined way with constant memory usage.

Here is a supposed transcript demonstrating how I want it to behave: (the `1`s and `2`s are the `Record`s retrieved from `get1` calls, and the `(,)`s represent computations happened immediately after each detection of group)

```
1
1
1
2
2
1
(["1","1","1"],["2","2"])
2
1
(["1"],["2"])
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
1
(["1","1","1","1"],["2","2","2","2"])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collecting lines of input in a streamlined way usually involves an iteratee-style library like pipes or conduit. I'll use pipes out of familiarity but something similar could probably be accomplished with conduit.

First, there's the matter of grouping. Pipes handles this with a low-level library called `pipes-group` that manages grouping into substreams without collecting elements into memory. (It is the basis of similar functionality in the `pipes-bytestring` and `pipes-text` libraries.)

pipes-group accomplishes this by splitting the input into multiple Producers delimited using `FreeT`. FreeT essentially allows for the construction of a "linked list" of producers.

```
import Control.Lens
import Pipes
import Pipes.Group
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

main = runEffect $ (concats . view groups) P.stdinLn >-> P.stdoutLn
```

This will group input lines (by `(==)`) but then immediately concatenate them back together, which is not very useful. To demonstrate that the grouping is really happening, we can use `intercalates`:

```
import Control.Lens
import Pipes
import Pipes.Group
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

main = runEffect $
         (intercalates (yield "!") . view groups) P.stdinLn >-> P.stdoutLn
```

This will output a "!" in between each group, which at least shows that the grouping is working properly. To collect the elements of the group together, we use the built-in support for the `foldl` library's streaming folds:

```
import Control.Lens
import Pipes
import Pipes.Group
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

main = runEffect $
         (folds (++) [] id . view groups) P.stdinLn >-> P.stdoutLn
```

Note that while stdin will be streamed in constant space, this will collect the entire groups into memory in the resulting lists, but of course there's no way to avoid that.

For more info, see the [pipes-group tutorial](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-group-1.0.2/docs/Pipes-Group-Tutorial.html) and the [foldl package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm looking into this package.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I didn't bother to decipher your code - so this is likely not quite what you need but hopefully close.  A better question should net a better answer.  Namely, if you describe clearly what you are trying to solve and your difficulty solving it in the most straight-forward manner rather than show the attempt you arrived at before giving up it might help.

So you want to read stdin and group the data by some computation on each line then run computations on the groups?  That English sentence almost directly translates to the needed Haskell:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function

main :: IO ()
main = do
  do input <- getContents
     print $ map computation (groupBy ((==) `on` grouper) (lines input))

grouper = id

computation = ("I see a block of stuff of length: " ++) . show . length
```

With the input/output:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
1
["I see a block of stuff of length: 6","I see a block of stuff of length: 9","I see a block of stuff of length: 1"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I need a solution which can deal with effectively infinite stream of records, using only constant memory, and do the processing as soon as each group is detected. I added the transcript of what my example code would look like when run.

Comment: @trVoldemort, the program in this answer does that.

Comment: @trVoldemory as Reid said, this is streaming and can operate in constant space.  Why would you think otherwise?  It send to her that you are reaching for more complex tools too quickly.

Comment: My apologies Thomas, I didn't realize `getContents` reads the input lazily. Now I agree that your answer is correct to my particularly framed question. However that's not quite what I want because of the actual form of my input -- instead of `stdin` (or a file), it only exposes it self with a function `get1 :: IO (Maybe Record)`, which with each call returns one record `Just record` unless the data is depleted, in which case it returns `Nothing`.  ( @ReidBarton )

Comment: Thomas, per your suggestions, I framed my questions to better suit my needs and made it clearer. Thanks for the advice. And if you are interested, I have isolated out the above [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192048/is-it-possible-to-have-a-lazy-version-of-sequence-without-using-unsafeios). ( @ReidBarton )

Comment: Well, it isn't obvious that `getContents` is lazy unless you know that it is implemented using `unsafeInterleaveIO`.