# Is it possible to have a lazy version of `sequence` without using `unsafeIO`s?

Tags: haskell

If I have a possibly infinite list of `IO`-monads, and I am guaranteed that their sequential execution will not be affected by other `IO`s, can I somehow make it lazily sequenced (evaluated)?

To clarify my point, here is some pseudo-Haskell code demonstrating what I had in mind:

```
main = do
    inputs <- sequence . repeat $ getLine -- we are forever stuck here
    mapM_ putStrLn inputs -- not going to run
```

Now, I know that in the particular example above, we can just use `getContents` to get the effect I want

```
main = do
    inputs <- return . lines =<< getContents
    mapM_ putStrLn inputs
```

but in my application the `IO` monads are not `getLine` but an external function `get1 :: IO (Maybe Record)`. However, this actually brings my point, because apparently `getContents` internally uses `unsafeIO`s to achieve this lazy-effect. My question is, is that necessary? (If you are interested in what exactly I want to do, please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182492/how-do-i-separate-a-stream-of-1s-and-2s-into-groups).)

Comment: The assumption "their sequential execution will not be affected by other `IO`s" can not be relied upon by "safe" routines, since we can always pass some `IO` action which violates said assumption. So, you really need some "unsafe" primitive at a certain point.

Comment: Are you triple double sure that their executions will not be affected by other `IO`s? For example, the obvious way to write your `getLine` example is `allLines = do { x <- unsafeInterleaveIO getLine; xs <- unsafeInterleaveIO allLines; return (x:xs) }`, yet this is subtly different from `allLines' = lines <$> getContents`. Can you see why?

Comment: Doesn't Rein Heinrich's answer in the linked thread already answer this one?

Comment: @ErikAllik If the problem isn't sequentially reading a handle or similar, but interleaving effects for some arbitrary IO action, then probably not. They probably want `unsafeInterleaveIO` somewhere, depending on what specifically they are doing. Or they want to reformulate the problem in terms of something that *can* be solved using iteratees.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this?

```
main = do
  let inputs = repeat getLine
  mapM_ (>>=putStrLn) inputs
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to bell the cat: *No*.

If you have something of type `IO a`, there is no way to get *any* information out of that `a` without fully executing that `IO` block. Conceptually, that `act :: IO a` could be defined as an arbitrary complicated set of actions, followed by then just producing a result dependent on a call to the system random number generator.

The entire purpose of `unsafeInterleaveIO` is perform what you're asking, and it can't be done without it.